# By clicking on HomePage button I want to show one component and by clicking on Cart button I want to show the other component (using boolean value)

Tags: reactjs, boolean, cart

by clicking on HomePage button I want to show the component HomePage and by clicking on Cart button I want to show the component Cart.
In my DevTools the App does not recognize the Cart component.. and if I click on one of the buttons its just stays in the default which is the HomePage (but it is recognize the boolean answer which is false when its HomePage and true when its Cart), Why it does not switch to the Cart component by clicking on the button? it seems like i connected the components in the right way, and also the function that does the action.

***its really important for me to keep it the simple way like I did, because I want to understand before I move on... (also with no routers or hooks! (: thanks! )**

Thank you so much everyone!

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css';
import Cart from './components/Cart.js'
import HomePage from './components/HomePage.js'

export default class App extends Component {

  state={

    flag: false
 
   }
 
 
 
 show=()=> {
  if(this.flag===true){
 
return(

  <div> <Cart/> </div>
)
}

  else {

return(

<div> <HomePage/> </div>

)
}

  
}

//////
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
     
     
     
         <button onClick={()=>{this.setState({flag:true})}}>Cart</button>
         <button onClick={()=>{this.setState({flag:false})}}>HomePage</button>
         {this.show()}
     
       </div>
       
     
       )
     
     }
    }
```

HomePage.js

```
import React from 'react'


export default function HomePage() {
    return (
        <div>
            H
        </div>
    )
}
```

Cart.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Cart() {
    return (
        <div>
            C
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: could you try the solution below and tell if it works then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your App.jsx like bellow:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css';
import Cart from './components/Cart.js'
import HomePage from './components/HomePage.js'

export default class App extends Component {

  state={

    flag: false
 
   }
 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
     
     
     
         <button onClick={()=>{this.setState({flag:true})}}>Cart</button>
         <button onClick={()=>{this.setState({flag:false})}}>HomePage</button>
         {this.state.flag && (
               <div><Cart/></div>
              )
         }
         {!this.state.flag && (
               <div><HomePage/></div>
              )
          }
     
       </div>
       
     
       )
     
     }
 }
```

also you can try this bellow:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css';
import Cart from './components/Cart.js'
import HomePage from './components/HomePage.js'

export default class App extends Component {

  state={

    flag: false
 
   }
const show=()=> {
  if(this.state.flag){
 
       return <Cart/> 
  }

  else {

       return <HomePage/> 
  }

 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
     
     
     
         <button onClick={()=>{this.setState({flag:true})}}>Cart</button>
         <button onClick={()=>{this.setState({flag:false})}}>HomePage</button>
         <div>{this.show}</div>
     
       </div>
       
     
       )
     
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank yon man, it works, Can you explain me what have you changed here?

Comment: The function should be declared like `const show = () => {` instead of `show = () ={` as you need to call inside of the `return` . Also during calling the function, you should call the variable only. Not the function. which means instead of `{this.show()}` , it should be `{this.show}`

Pleasure is mine. Hope I was helpful

Comment: Thanks. glad that the answer was helpful and worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Hi could you use show function as such ***this.state.flag***

```
  show = () => {
    if (this.state.flag === true) {
      return (
        <div>
          <Cart />
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <HomePage />
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/red-grass-fdxq9?file=/src/index.js I tried it here ..It worked could you check